# Best way to figure out if a log entry ended abruptly?

Tags: grep, logs

I have a previously broken script with a log file ending abruptly in the middle. It's obvious from the timestamps when looking at each single case. Is there a way to automatically grep for all such cases?

Example of a healthy ending with a proper "payone_cancel.php end".

```
2023-03-21T08:41:04+00:00       DEBUG       paypal  paypal_cancel.php begin
2023-03-21T08:41:04+00:00       DEBUG       paypal  params = {"id":123,"old_status":"","new_status":"DD"}
2023-03-21T08:41:04+00:00       DEBUG       paypal  JPATH_ROOT = [ROOT]
2023-03-21T08:41:04+00:00       DEBUG       paypal  PaypalCancel params = {"id":123,"old_status":"","new_status":"DD"}
2023-03-21T08:41:04+00:00       DEBUG       paypal  new_status is not EE or empty string, nothing to do
2023-03-21T08:41:04+00:00       DEBUG       paypal  paypal_cancel.php end
```

Example of faulty state where new timestamp appears before the proper "paypal_cancel end" line:

```
2023-02-17T20:57:41+00:00       DEBUG       paypal  paypal_cancel.php begin
2023-02-17T20:57:41+00:00       DEBUG       paypal  params = {"id":"123","old_status":"EE","new_status":"EE"}
2023-02-17T20:57:41+00:00       DEBUG       paypal  JPATH_ROOT = [ROOT]
2023-02-17T20:57:41+00:00       DEBUG       paypal  PaypalCancel params = {"id":"123","old_status":"EE","new_status":"EE"}
2023-02-17T22:00:27+00:00       DEBUG       paypal  --- frontend paypal gateway begin ---
```

`grep -l` might not work, since the number of lines are different for lots of different cases.

I might have to learn awk... Again.

Comment: I'd suggest you can run it with whatever debug facilites php offers

Comment: @NicolasFormichella The error happened in February, so it's not broken anymore. I only have the logs to figure out how many customers are affected.

Comment: Added new wording to make it clearer.

Comment: Wouldn't the timestamp sometimes be **expected** to change during a transaction and, if so, what's the real criteria to determine breakage?

Comment: @EdMorton Sadly yes, there are false positives with my posted solution. For us, this didn't matter much, because we had errors only during certain known dates. To get a completely correct analysis, the logging would have to be more disciplined, so that a breakage could be easy to detect. E.g. always have an "end" trace for each function.

Comment: OK, then why not describe finding a `begin` after a `begin` with no `end` in between as your requirement then so you don't have false positives? Your example seems to have 2 different types of `begin` - `paypal_cancel.php begin` and `--- frontend paypal gateway begin ---`, are those the only 2 `begin`s that can exist in your data? Is `paypal_cancel.php end` the only `end`?

Comment: @EdMorton Good idea. I've already used my previous solution to fix all issues I could find tho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```bash
grep -F 'old_status":"DD","new_status":"EE' -A1 | \
awk '{if (prev_line ~ /PaypalCancel/ && time != $1) print prev_line; time = $1; prev_line = $0}'
```

This contains false positives if a second passed during the logging, but it's good enough.

The trick is to store previous line and time column in variables and then use that when comparing.